# How to find a specific value in an entire worksheet then return the specific range where the value was found

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm creating a new vba code for finding a specific value in a worksheet and returning the range where I find the value.

I've already tried the `COUNTIF` function and it only returns the number that it found on the worksheet. What I want is to return where specific range where the specific value was found.

Comment: If you show your current code I'm sure you'll get useful suggestions.  Find() or Match() seem like good ways to go here.

Comment: Would you like the a large range, like the row or column where it was found, or the exact cell?